# Amazon Aurora 1.8 Load Data From S3 - Cannot Instantiate S3 Client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

With the latest Aurora update (1.8), the command `LOAD DATA FROM S3` was introduced. Has anyone gotten this to work?  After upgrading to 1.8, I followed the setup guide **[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Authorizing.AWSServices.html#Aurora.Authorizing.AWSServices.CreateRole)** to create the Role to allow access from RDS to S3.

After rebooting the server and trying to run the command

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://<bucket_name>/prefix' INTO TABLE table_name
```

in SQL Workbench/J, I get the errors:

```
Warnings:
S3 API returned error: Missing Credentials: Cannot instantiate S3 Client
S3 API returned error: Failed to instantiate S3 Client
Internal error: Unable to initialize S3Stream
```

Are there any additional steps required?  Can I only run this from the SDK? I don't see that mentioned anywhere in the documents

Comment: I have the same problem. I have discussed it in the AWS forum, and I have apparently set it all up correctly. The amazon guy helping me has escalated the issue. If I get a resolution, I will pass it along.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, was escalated.  Must be a common issue.

Comment: @Ray i got in touch with the Aurora team, they are rolling out a patch for this soon.

Comment: Any updates here? I'm having the same issue even after applying all the suggestions below from @Ray

Comment: You get this error if your S3 file does not exist and depending on your DB collation it may be case sensitive. Took me forever to debug this issue. If you've changed your collation you might notice this suddenly...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same issue. I tried adding AmazonS3FullAccess to the IAM role that my RDS instances were using...no joy.

After poking around, I went into the RDS console, to Clusters. Selected my Aurora cluster and clicked Manage IAM Roles. It gave me a drop-down, I selected the IAM role (same one that the individual instances were using).

Once I did that, all was well and data load was nice and fast.

So, there are (for us) 5 steps/components:

1) The S3 bucket and bucket policy to allow a user to upload the object

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1453918146601",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1453917898368",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account id>:<user/group/role>/<IAM User/Group/Role>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The "Principal" would be whatever IAM user, group or role will be uploading the data files to the bucket so that the RDS instance can import the data.

2) The IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1486490368000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is pretty simple with the Policy Generator.

3) Create the IAM Role:

This role should be assigned the IAM policy above. You can probably do an inline policy, too, if you're not going to use this policy for other roles down the line, but I like the idea of having a defined policy that I can reference later if I have a need.

4) Configure a Parameter Group that your cluster/instances will use to set the aws_default_s3_role value to the ARN of the role from #3 above.

5) Configure the Aurora Cluster by going to Clusters, selecting your cluster, selecting Manage IAM Roles and setting the IAM Role for your DB Cluster

At least for me, these steps worked like a charm.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Marking this as the answer. Although originally the issue was due to an issue with the Aurora release itself, that issue has since been resolved and most people experiencing the issue now can resolve it following these steps.

Comment: It still didn't work until I cloned the RDS instance.

Comment: I already had the VPC endpoint installed, trying to figure out why there was a permission issue. Following the above checklist resolved it for me. Thanks a million!

Comment: What a hidden option + seems redundant to parameter group

Comment: Tried all this with no luck, then I realized that in the permission group roles, I was entering the role name where it actually wants the ARN for the role. I know that sounds silly now but ... Anyway, once I did that, it still didn't work until I rebooted the DB. Then it all came together. Thank you for this post.

Answer (score 7):

If the only error is `Internal error: Unable to initialize S3Stream` and it throws this error immediately, possible culprits are:

- typo in the bucket or object name
- bucket created in different region than database
- bucket or object name is not specified according to [the syntax for specifying a path to files stored on an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html): s3-*region*://*bucket-name*/*file-name-or-prefix*

> The path includes the following values:
>
> - region (optional) – The AWS Region that contains the Amazon S3 bucket to load from. This value is optional. If you don't specify a region value, then Aurora loads your file from Amazon S3 in the same region as your DB cluster.
> - bucket-name – The name of the Amazon S3 bucket that contains the data to load. Object prefixes that identify a virtual folder path are supported.
> - file-name-or-prefix – The name of the Amazon S3 text file or XML file, or a prefix that identifies one or more text or XML files to load. You can also specify a manifest file that identifies one or more text files to load.

Comment: If you have unwittingly, created the bucket in a different region from the db, specifying the region solves the issue.

Comment: My Aurora access to RDS was not rightly setup got Error Code: 1815. Internal error: Unable to initialize S3Stream

Answer (score 3):

After all the suggestions above, as a final step, I had to add a VPC Endpoint to S3. After that, everything started working.

Answer (score 3):

March 2019:

RDS console doesn't have the option to change role anymore. What worked for me is to add the role via CLI and then reboot the writer instance.

```
aws rds add-role-to-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier my-cluster --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/AllowAuroraS3Role
```

Comment: Man, this is bizarre, I just configured this using the console last November for another account and now that option is gone from the console. This is messed up.

Comment: It's under the "Connectivity & Security" tab now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess or AmazonS3FullAccess policy to the role you set up in IAM. This step was not included in the setup guide.

Go to IAM -> Roles in the AWS console, select the role you are using, click 'attach policy', then scroll way down to the S3 policies and pick one.

Comment: I did this during the setup.  Amazon has escalated my support ticket.

Comment: hmmm... That's what fixed it for me. It's a very new feature - I guess we pioneers have to suffer a little so those who come after have an easier time.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was missing the step to add the created RDS role to my S3 bucket. Once I add it, it worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Amazon Aurora team and they confirmed there are edge cases with some of the servers having this issue.  They are rolling out a patch to fix the issue soon, but in the mean time manually applied the patch to my cluster.

Comment: Hi aarbor, It looks like I've got the same issue. Can you tell me what the patch is and how you applied it? Thanks Adam

Comment: Check console for latest maintenance patches and apply them, that should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced multiple occasions this error could occur.

1. The error was thrown after running 'LOAD' sql for a while (around 220s), which is a suspicious time-out case. Finally I found my RDS's Subnet Group only have one outbound excluding the one to S3. By adding the outbound rule can fix this issue.
2. The error was thrown immediately (0.2s). I was successfully loading data from S3 before, but suddenly with a change on the S3 url, this error occurred again. I was using a wrong S3 URL. Because I wanted to use S3 prefix instead of file. check the 'Load' syntax to make your sql right.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by following step 2 to 5 and by creating VPC endpoint for S3 access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as I was trying to `LOAD DATA FROM S3` using MySQL Workbench. I was already able to successfully `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` and so I knew my connection was working.

I closely followed all of the AWS documentation instructions for [Loading data into an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster from text files in an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html).

In my case, I had not correctly followed instruction steps 3 & 4 (See list of instructions under subheading "Giving Aurora access to Amazon S3" at link above.

What fixed it for me:

1. From Amazon RDS, I selected "Parameter Groups" in the navigation
   pane on the left.
2. Then I clicked on my newly created custom DB cluster parameter
   group (step 3 from the link above).
3. From within my custom group, I searched for
   `aurora_load_from_s3_role` and then in the "Values" entry box, I
   copy/pasted the ARN for the Role that I had just created in step 2 of the
   instructions into this box and clicked Save (step 4 from the link above).

I went back to MySQL Workbench and reran my `LOAD DATA FROM S3` command and it worked!